# Get value from service from different activites

Tags: android

Hello Im trying to make a time counter that should work on the app in background or when the user leaves the activity.

Its working fine and Im able to get the time from my service and make him run even when the app is in background.

My problem is that when I leave the activity that bind the service and reenter the activity I get different values for the same service variable.

When I first call `startTime()` I get the same number in my both log calls `Log.i("time 2", time+"")` and `Log.i("time", time+"")`. When I leave the activity and reenter it I get the log for `Log.i("time 2", time+"")` keep couting the correct time but `Log.i("time", time+"")` always showing 0.

How do I get the value of `time` from the last time I started the service.

This is my service code:

```
public class OnTheWayCounterService extends Service{

    long time;
    boolean stopThread;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public boolean isRunning()
    {
        return !stopThread;
    }

    public void stopTime()
    {
        stopThread = true;  
        time = 0;
    }

    public void startTime()
    {
        stopThread = false;
        startStopWatch();
        time = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void startStopWatch()
    {

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {               
                time++;

                Log.i("time 2", time+"");

                if(stopThread == false)
                    startStopWatch();

            }
        }, 1000);   
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public OnTheWayCounterService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return OnTheWayCounterService.this;
        }
    }

    public String getOnTheWayTime()
    {
        long hours = time / 3600;
        long minutes = time / 60;
        long seconds = time % 60;

        Log.i("time", time+"");

        String sMinutes;
        String sSeconds;

        if(minutes < 10)
            sMinutes = "0" + minutes;
        else
            sMinutes = minutes+"";

        if(seconds < 10)
            sSeconds = "0" + seconds;
        else
            sSeconds = seconds+"";

        return hours + ":" + sMinutes + ":" + sSeconds;
    }

}
```

This is in the activity that uses the service:

```
    public void startStopWatch()
        {

            onTheWayTime = (TextView) featureList.findViewById(R.id.travel_time);

            Handler handler = new Handler();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if(mService.isRunning())
                            {
                                Log.i("time time", mService.getOnTheWayTime());

                                onTheWayTime.setText(mService.getOnTheWayTime());
                                startStopWatch();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 1000);

        }

    @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // Bind to LocalService
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnTheWayCounterService.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            Log.i("onStart", "onStart");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            // Unbind from the service
            if (mBound) {
                unbindService(mConnection);
                mBound = false;
            }
        }

        private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                    IBinder service) {
                // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
                Log.i("bind", "bind");

                LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
                mService = binder.getService();
                mBound = true;

  if(mService.isRunning() == false)
                mService.startTime();




            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                mBound = false;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the onStop

```
@Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            // Unbind from the service
            if (mBound) {
                unbindService(mConnection);
                mBound = false;
            }
        }
```

I removed it and its working.